# How to add header separator between childitem in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I wish to add "Header" separator like this between child items in my listview, how can i achieve it. Below is my working listview code.

[image]

ElistCBox.java

```
public class ElistCBox extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox2";
    private ColorAdapter expListAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        groupNames.add("AAA");
        groupNames.add("BBB");
        groupNames.add("CCC");


        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>(); 

        ArrayList<Color> color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "ABC", false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "DEF", true ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "GHI", false ));

        colors.add( color );

        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "ABC", false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "DEF", true ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "GHI", false ));

        colors.add( color );

        color = new ArrayList<Color>();
        color.add( new Color( "ABC", false ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "DEF", true ) ); 
        color.add( new Color( "GHI", false ));

        colors.add( color );


        expListAdapter = new ColorAdapter( this,groupNames, colors );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );
    }

    public void onContentChanged  () {
        super.onContentChanged();
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onContentChanged" );
    }

    public boolean onChildClick(
            ExpandableListView parent, 
            View v, 
            int groupPosition,
            int childPosition,
            long id) {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onChildClick: "+childPosition );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
        if( cb != null )
            cb.toggle();
        return false;
    }
}
```

ColorAdapter.java

```
public class ColorAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, 
                        ArrayList<String> groups,
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colors ) { 
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.colors = colors;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return colors.get( groupPosition ).get(childPosition );
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024+childPosition );                          // Max 1024 children per group
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
        Color c = (Color)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
        TextView color = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( color != null )
            color.setText( c.getColor() );
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
        cb.setChecked( c.getState() );
        return v;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return colors.get( groupPosition ).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get( groupPosition );        
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long)( groupPosition*1024 );  // To be consistent with getChildId
    } 

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if( convertView != null )
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false); 
        String gt = (String)getGroup( groupPosition );
        TextView colorGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.childname );
        if( gt != null )
            colorGroup.setText( gt );
        return v;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    } 

    public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {} 
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}


}
```

Color.java

```
   public class Color {
        public String color = null;
        public boolean state = false;

        public Color( String color, boolean state ) {
            this.color = color;
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public boolean getState() {
            return state;
        }

    }
```

child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="20px"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="19dp"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

group_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Please select the programs/episodes you watched last week for which you will submit response"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_New"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error are you getting while using `ExpandableListView` ?

Comment: Ankit - There is no error, it is working code, its just that i need to add separator in between as shown in example picture above

Comment: Since it seems you're not expanding the groups in ExpandableListView, https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders might be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to usage of `ExpandableListView`, I assume you used it for similar section kind of effect..

- To go ahead with this approach only, you can programmatically `expand` all the groups and then `disable` collapsing of groups `onClick`.
- Or you can use `SectionListView`, there are [various libraries](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=SectionListView) present out there for this. Along with additional quality of `pinning` the sections.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the above shown pic, there is no need of using the `ExpandableListView`. Simple you can go with `ListView` with multiple view types by using

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0; // return the item view type
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
```

The framework uses your view type to decide which views to hand you via convertView in your `getView()` method.  Here is small example that makes you understand better

```
public class StockAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    // declaration of fields.
    private ArrayList<StockItemBean> stockListItems;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return adapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //return the item type TYPE_ITEM or TYPE_SEPARATOR
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        // for getting the convert view for the stock fragment grid item.
        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            //Initialize the convert to header
                break;
            case TYPE_ITEM:
            //Initialize the convert to header
                break;
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            // update the data for the list item
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            //update the data for the header
            break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

    }
}
```

outline the general flow:
1.You bind data to your AdapterView using an adapter.
2. The AdapterView tries to display items that are visible to the user.
3. The framework calls getItemViewType for row n, the row it is about to display.
4. The framework checks its recycled views pool for views of row n's type. 
5. It doesn't find any because no views have been recycled yet.
getView is called for row n.
6. You call getItemViewType for row n to determine what type of view you should use.
7. You use an if/switch statement to inflate a different xml file depending on which view type is required.
8. You fill the view with information.
9. You return the view, exiting getView, and your row's view is displayed to the user.
Now, when a view is recycled by scrolling off the screen it goes into a recycled views pool that is managed by the framework. These are essentially organized by view type so that a view of the correct type is given to you in convertView parameter in your getView method:

1. The framework again calls getItemViewType for the row it wants to display.
2. This time, there is a view in the recycled pool of the appropriate type.
3. The recycled view is passed to you as the convertView parameter to your getView method.
4. You fill the recycled view with new information and return it.